# Javascript categorical object array sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, categories

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
let array = [

    {id: 0, type: "Office" },
    {id: 1, type: "Security" },
    {id: 2, type: "Office" },
    {id: 3, type: "Security" },
    {id: 4, type: "Security" },
    {id: 5, type: "Office" },
    {id: 6, type: "Agent" },
    {id: 7, type: "Security" }

];
```

I need to sort it according custom categorical sequence set, i.e. ["Office", "Agent", "Security"] to get the following output:

```
var array = [
    {id: 0, type: "Office" },
    {id: 2, type: "Office" },
    {id: 5, type: "Office" },
    {id: 6, type: "Agent" }
    {id: 1, type: "Security" },
    {id: 3, type: "Security" },
    {id: 4, type: "Security" },
    {id: 7, type: "Security" }
];
```

Didn't find any proper solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the sort order.

```js
let array = [
    {id: 0, type: "Office" },
    {id: 1, type: "Security" },
    {id: 2, type: "Office" },
    {id: 3, type: "Security" },
    {id: 4, type: "Security" },
    {id: 5, type: "Office" },
    {id: 6, type: "Agent" },
    {id: 7, type: "Security" }
];
const order = ["Office", "Agent", "Security"]
array.sort((a,b)=>order.indexOf(a.type)-order.indexOf(b.type));
console.log(array);
```